# MySQL: сформировать топ юзеров по количеству рефереров

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица `users` такого вида:

```
uid | ref
---------
 1  |  0
---------
 2  |  1
---------
 3  |  0
---------
 4  |  1
---------
 5  |  2
---------
```

то есть юзер и реферер. Мне нужно получить топ рефоводов, а именно посчитать, сколько у кого рефералов и вывести, отсортировав по убыванию.

Пробовал так:

```
SELECT COUNT(`uid`) FROM `users` WHERE ref = (SELECT uid FROM users)
```

но так возвращает `Subquery returns more than 1 row`.

Так работает:

```
SELECT COUNT(`uid`) FROM `t_users` WHERE ref IN (SELECT uid FROM t_users)
```

но как вывести, на какой именно `uid` посчитан `count()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
SELECT `ref`, COUNT(*) AS `cnt`
FROM `users`
GROUP BY `ref`
ORDER BY `cnt` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так (в синтаксисе мог немного наврать):

```
select `ref`, count(*) from `users` group by `ref` order by count(*) desc limit 10
```

Comment: в mysql нет `top 10`

Comment: вопрос подправлен

Comment: @zenden2k, спасибо.